# How do I stop my Win10 computer from sleep after 3 minutes of inactivity?

Tags: windows-10, sleep

Given that there's no Windows 10 driver for my battery the battery is installed without a driver (Sony VAIO).

In the power management my computer is set to sleep never but some process still seems to send it to sleep. Is there a way I can figure out which process is responsible? Alternatively is there a way to simulate that my computer is always active and thus won't sleep due to inactivity?

Comment: Did you already try searching for an updated `Display adapter` driver?

Comment: @Run5k : I searched for a driver on the Sony website and didn't found any.

Comment: Possibly take a look at the hardware vendor's web site and check for the made/model number?  In my experience, the first place I look when there are problems that are potentially related to the Windows power scheme is to see if there is a newer driver for the graphics card that may alleviate the problem.

Comment: @Run5k : There's no official driver for Win10.

Comment: Perhaps one for Windows 8?  Again, from my perspective that would be the most likely suspect.  Does your `Display adapter` within `Device Manager` show a make and model number, or is it simply a generic entry like "Standard VGA..." ?

Comment: @Run5k : It shows a generic Microsoft ACPI compliant controller.

Comment: Ultimately, that is probably the root cause of your problem:  if there isn't an officially supported driver for your `Display adapter`, you are destined to have problems of this nature related to your power scheme.  If you don't mind me asking, how did this scenario evolve?  Did you manually initiate a Windows 10 upgrade on that machine?  As I recall, typically the automatic upgrade (when it was free through Windows Update prior to July 29th) won't occur if there isn't a graphics card driver available for that system.

Comment: Yes, I manually updated. But I'm fine with not having a driver installed that tells me how much battery is left. I'm not fine with my computer constantly going to sleep.

Comment: Understood, but once again that is probably the the root cause of your problem. I would do some additional online research to find the specific make and model of your graphics card within that laptop. If the hardware vendor previously released a device driver for Windows 8 or Windows 8.1, there is a decent chance that it will work within Windows 10. If not, you will most likely be faced with a decision: either live with the current problem, or drop back to the older operating system.

Comment: @Run5k : My problem has nothing to do with graphic cards but with power management and there's no driver to install.

Comment: Please trust me when I emphasize that in a Windows operating system, your graphics card driver directly affects your power options and the missing driver is most likely the cause of your problem.  You can potentially double-check your BIOS settings, but that would be your only other option. Here is a Microsoft article that helps confirm that:  [Windows polls not only the (video) driver but also the BIOS before it enables any sleep states](https://support.microsoft.com/fi-fi/help/980869/about-how-to-troubleshoot-power-plans-in-windows-7).  So if you don't have a driver, that is problematic.

Comment: @Run5k : My graphic card has no missing driver. My battery misses a driver. It's also likely that the problem is caused by this but this knowledge doesn't help at all with solving the issue.

Comment: We  seem to have a small misunderstanding in terminology.  I specifically asked you *" Does your `Display adapter` within `Device Manager` show a make and model number, or is it simply a generic entry like "Standard VGA,"* and you essentially said that it didn't.  Your `Display adapter` actually **is** your graphics card, so when you said that it told me that your graphics card did/does have a missing driver.

Comment: @Run5k : I answered the question in the way that makes sense to speak about the device that I have uninstalled and that's the battery controller.

Comment: Your situation is understandably frustrating, but I very clearly asked about the `Display adapter` within `Device Manager`.  We are always glad to help, but when we ask questions in an attempt to aid you in solving your problem please don't change the meaning of what we said to what you believe it *should* be. If you are going to rely upon our expertise, you need to answer the questions as they are asked.

Answer (score 0):

Go to 'Settings' app -> Devices -> Power Management and click 'Advanced power settings'. There you can change the 'display timeout' and 'sleep timeout' to whatever you want. Changes take effect instantly but make sure you changed the settings of the correct 'power plan' (there are 3 built-in).

Comment: They are set to never.  That's not what letting my system sleep.