# Windows 10 is going to sleep after 2 min whatever the settings are

Tags: windows-10, sleep

My laptop on Windows 10 is going to sleep even though I've set Screen and Sleep to `Never` in the `Power & sleep settings`. I've also checked that screensaver is to `None`.

I suspect that the problem might come from the "Battery saver mode". When I click on the battery, `Battery saver` is locked and I cannot click on it (see screenshot). Can this explain my problem?

Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Is this a company-owned computer that might be subject to Active Directory/Group Policy rules?  It may also be an issue with your video card driver, [as discussed here](https://superuser.com/q/1183993/118184).

Comment: Welcome to the site. Beyond the above question about this being a company computer, I don't believe you can switch to `Battery Saver` while it is plugged in and charging. Have you tried to create a new power profile?

Comment: No, this is not a company-owned computer; it is my own. Never mind my suggestion and screenshot, I think I have mis-interpreted the greyed Battery saver on my screenshot. I thought it was locked on while actually I suppose it means it is off and I cannot turn it on.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution that worked out for me:

1. Click on the windows icon
2. Type regedit
3. Right-click on regedit icon, click Run as administrator
4. Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20\7bc4a2f9-d8fc-4469-b07b-33eb785aaca0
5. Double click on Attributes
6. Enter number 2.
7. Go to Advanced power settings (click on Windows button, write power options, click on Power Options, in the selected plan click on the Change plan settings, click on the Change advanced power settings).
8. Click on the Change settings that are currently unavailable
9. Click Sleep, then System unattended sleep timeout, then change these settings from 2 Minutes to 20 for example.
   That's it! At least it works for me...

Answer (score 0):

While this is most likely a software issue, it's possible that the battery is having a physical problem.  Since this is a company laptop, perhaps they have spare batteries or another laptop of the same model to swap with to see if the same problem recurs.

Comment: This is not a company-owned laptop. I just tried with the battery out (and plugged in, obviously). Looks like it's working (i.e. not going to sleep after 2 min)! Any idea how I can solve this issue without having to remove the battery?